# Turn Laravel Query into Key Value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, collections

I am just starting to learn Laravel and I have a query result that looks like:

```
[
  {
    servicename: "test",
    thing: "1"
  },
  {
    servicename: "test",
    thing: "2"
  },
  {
    servicename: "test",
    thing: "3"
  },
  {
    servicename: "test2",
    thing: "4"
  },
  {
    servicename: "test2",
    toothnum: "5"
  },
  {
    servicename: "test2",
    thing: "6"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to turn this into something like:

```
  {
    services: {
      test:[
         "1",
         "2",
         "3"
       ]
      test2:[
         "4",
         "5",
         "6"
       ]
    }

  }
```

Basically I want the result set to be something I could loop in my view so I can display the "things" for each service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by looping your array like this:

```
$output_arr = array();
foreach($your_arr as $val)
{
 $output_arr[$val['servicename']][] = $val['thing'];
}

print_r($output_arr);
```